# Can IBM Cloud Watson recognize the same person across multiple images?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I want to create a gallery service that clusters images based on different characteristics, chief among them being faces matched across multiple images.

I've been considering the IBM Cloud for this, but i can't find a definitive yes or no answer to whether Watson supports Face recognition (on top of detection) so the same person is identified across multiple images, like [AWS Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-your-own-face-recognition-service-using-amazon-rekognition/) and [Azure CognitiveServices Face API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/) do.

The concrete scenario i want to implement is this: Given photos A.jpg and B.jpg Watson should be able to tell that A.jpg has a face corresponding to person X, and B.jpg has another face that looks similar to the one in A.jpg. Ideally, it should do this automatically and give me face id values for each detected face.

Has anyone tackled this with Watson before? Is it doable in a simple manner without much code or ML techniques on top of the vanilla Watson face detection?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Watson to do basic face detection on the CLI. Are you wanting to recognize a particular individual after training on images of that individual? Could you clarify your question. Here is what I can answer, if you have a Watson API key you can run this for example on a terminal:

```
curl -X POST --form "images_file=@path/to/image.jpg" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/detect_faces?api_key={your_api_key}&version=2016-05-20"
```

That will recognize the individual in the photo and give other categorical information about the person such as age, sex, etc. And if they are famous it will give further category information.

Comment: That's the basic face detection and it works great. My problem right now is this: Assume a subject, named "X" for example, is detected in the file A.jpg and another file B.jpg exists. I want to know if "X" is in A.jpg AND B.jpg

Comment: Okay, harder problem. I think if you edit your original question to be more specific you might get better answers.